# Javascript table menu opens up with all tables already collapsed, why?

Tags: javascript, html-table

I have a simple menu with collapsing tables, working with Javascript. My problem is when I open it in the browser it comes up with all tables already collapsed! How can I open it with the menu sections "closed", to then collapse each section only onclick? I know it's in the Javascript but I'm new to it so bear with me... Thank you!

Here's the basic code:

```
<head>
<script>
function doCollapse(rowname)
{
theElement = document.getElementById(rowname);
if(theElement.style.display == 'none'){
theElement.style.display = '';
}else {
theElement.style.display = 'none';
}
return false;
}
</script>
</head>


<body>
<table>
<tr>
  <td>
    <p1 onClick=" doCollapse ('r1');">JQ</p>
  </td></tr>
<tr>
  <td id="r1">ver biografia</td></tr>

<tr>
  <td>
   <p2 onClick=" doCollapse ('r2');">Obras</p>
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="r2">lista</td></tr>

<tr>
  <td>
 <p3 onClick=" doCollapse ('r3');">Exposições</p>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td id="r3">lista</td></tr>

</table>
</body>
</code>
```

Comment: Could I suggest correcting your HTML `p1`, `p2` and `p3` are *not* HTML elements (use a `p`, the element that you're *closing*). This isn't (or is massively unlikely to be) your problem, but if you're going to use HTML, *please* use it properly. Otherwise error-handling makes *everything* harder than it needs to be.

Comment: of course! the p_nr's don't make any sense...

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using pure javascript and not a library like [jquery](http://jquery.com), I'd suggest a couple of modification to easily target your elements. Try to put the items to show and hide inside a `span` so you can use `document.getElementsByTagName` and then add the Id to those spans rather than on `td`. My concern was that you have more `td` in your code, so you using `document.getElementsByTagName` would affect them as well, which is not what you need. However, you need to be careful that my solution would also suffer from that side effect if you have more spans in your code, which is likely, so you need to take this consideration before you implement this live.  Here is the code and you can see a [live demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/QwfSe/)

```
<head>
<script>
    function init(){
        var numberOfRows = document.getElementsByTagName('span').length;
        for (var i = 0; i < numberOfRows; i++){
       document.getElementsByTagName('span')[i].style.display = 'none';
        }

    }

function doCollapse(rowname)
{
theElement = document.getElementById(rowname);
if(theElement.style.display == 'none'){
theElement.style.display = 'inline';
}else {
theElement.style.display = 'none';
}
return false;
}
</script>
</head>


<body onload="init()">
<table>
<tr>
  <td>
    <p onClick=" doCollapse ('r1');">JQ</p>
  </td></tr>
<tr>
    <td><span id="r1">ver biografia</span></td></tr>

<tr>
  <td>
   <p onClick=" doCollapse ('r2');">Obras</p>
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><span id="r2">lista</span></td></tr>

<tr>
  <td>
 <p onClick=" doCollapse ('r3');">Exposições</p>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><span id="r3">lista</span></td></tr>

</table>
```